# Integral over scalar product of eigenfunction of momentum operator and harmonic oscillator one

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, fourier-transform

Recently I've met following expression:
$$
\tag 2 \sum_{n}f(n)\int dp~ |\langle p | n\rangle|^{2} =  2\pi \sum_{n}f(n).
$$
Here $|n>$ is eigenfunction of harmonic oscillator with energy $$E_{n} = \omega \left(n + \frac{1}{2} \right),$$ $|p>$ is eigenfunction of momentum operator (without normalization constant), $$|p> = e^{ipx},$$ $$\langle p|p{'}\rangle = 2\pi \delta (p - p{'}). $$

How to prove $(2)$?

Comment: $(2\pi)^{-1/2}\langle p , \cdot\rangle$ is the fourier transform on $L^2$. $\lvert n\rangle$ has norm one on $L^2$, and the Fourier transform is unitary (i.e. preserves the $L^2$ norm).

Comment: |<p|n>|^2 = <n|p><p|n> and the integral over p of |p><p| = 2 pi due to the way you've normaliized these states, so you are left with the squared norm of |n> which is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\sum _nf(n)\int \mathrm{d}p\, |\left< p|n\right> |^2=\sum _nf(n)\int \mathrm{d}p\int \mathrm{d}q\, \left< n|p\right> \left< p|n\right> =2\pi \sum _nf(n)\left< n|n\right> =2\pi \cdot \sum _nf(n),
$$
where I used the fact that
$$
\int \mathrm{d}p\, \left| p\right> \left< p\right| =2\pi,
$$
which follows from
$$
\left< p|q\right> =2\pi \delta (p-q).
$$